# Send SMS on python

Tags: python, gsm, modem

I'm trying to send a SMS with a GSM Modem and python. But it's not working  at all.  I have this code here:

```
import time
import serial

recipient = "+hereisthenumber"
message = "Hello, World!"

phone = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",  115200, timeout=5)
try:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(b'ATZ\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(b'AT+CMGF=1\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(b'AT+CMGS="' + recipient.encode() + b'"\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(message.encode() + b"\r")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(bytes([26]))
    time.sleep(0.5)
finally:
    phone.close()
```

**And this is the return:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modem.py", line 8, in <module>
    phone = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",  115200, timeout=5)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 286, in open
    self._update_dtr_state()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 623, in _update_dtr_state
    fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCMBIS, TIOCM_DTR_str)
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: What happens if you try `socat - /dev/ttyUSB0` with this device. Make sure you are using the correct device. Simply unplug, plug in again and then a `dmesg` there you find the correct device. All these commands as superuser on the shell

Comment: I'm making this a comment since I know this isn't a direct answer to your question. An alternative solution is the Twilio API -- easy to use , very portable, cheap, and no dependence on a specific piece of hardware.

Comment: So i have change the "ttyUSB0" to "ttyS0", and now don't return an ERROR, but still don't work.